# How to compile memcached from github sources?

Tags: clang, memcached

[GitHub](https://github.com/memcached/memcached) has no `configure` file. Only `configure.am`.
No idea, how to handle it.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to run the [`autogen.sh` script](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/autogen.sh) from the checkout, and make sure that your build system has `aclocal`, `autoheader`, `automake`, and `autoconf` installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memcached use [Autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Build_System) to build source, as you got `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am`, follow these steps to build the source:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

The binary is generated now, find the location by running `find * -name memcached`.

Comment: +1 This is captured in BUILD file of memcached source. https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/BUILD#L14-L16